# Entity Framework Composite Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to update my `entity`, but `entity` has two composite keys. And throws an error

> The property  is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as
> modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an
> identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke
> 'SaveChanges', and then associate the dependent with the new
> principal.

Context

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Type, e.Id });
});
```

Mapper

```cs
CreateMap<OriginAnimal, NewInformationAnimal>()
    .ReverseMap();
```

Controller

```cs
Animal updateAnimal = _mapper.Map(originalAnimal, newInformationAnimal);
_animalRepository.UpdateAnimal(updateAnimal);
```

AnimalRepository

```cs
public void UpdateAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    _animalContext.Entry(animal).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _animalContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is an example

Update Entity with two composite keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because in your **updateAnimal** you changed one of the two properties of the composite primary key (Type or Id), and you are not allowed to do so. Indeed, the error appears immediately soon when you try to mark the Entry State like **Modified** (I verified it), before "SaveChanges()". The solution, obviously, is the proposed one to delete the dependent childs (saving the modified principal also), and to create them again with the new composite foreign key.